# Constructor injection with unknown value

Tags: spring, constructor-injection

Using constructor based dependency injection you can replace something like this

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Bar bar = new Bar(foo);
Baz baz = new Baz(bar);
```

with this

```
Baz baz = (Baz) context.getBean('baz');
```

with xml that looks like this

```
<beans>
   <bean id="foo" class="Foo"/>
   <bean id="bar" class="Bar>
       <constructor-arg ref="foo"/>
   </bean>
   <bean id="baz" class="Baz"/>
       <constructor-arg ref="bar"/>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

My question is what if your code looked something like this

```
var value = 42;
Foo foo = new Foo(value);
Bar bar = new Bar(foo);
Baz baz = new Baz(bar);
```

where 'value' is an argument that can be anything. I would like to be able to call something like this where it somehow knows what to do with 'value'

```
Baz baz = (Baz) context.getBean('baz', value);
```

Is something similar to what I'm asking available in Spring to deal with this situation?

Comment: You should probably describe your actual problem in more details. What you are asking may be possible (not directly, but with some hacked [PropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) and prototype beans), but I think there must be a better way to do it.

Comment: The problem is if I just have a 'value' can I skip over having to create 'foo' and 'bar, and create 'baz' straight away passing it 'value.

Comment: Once you call `getBean` (and pass the constructor args, assuming that was possible), there's little dependency injection left. What's wrong with a mere method in your application code: `Baz getBaz(int value) { return new Baz(new Bar(new Foo(value))); }`? A DI container is meant to inject dependencies that you do not (want to) control in any way. I mean, think of what happens with your `context.getBean()` code when you change `Baz` to be constructed differently (and perhaps not require a `Foo` -- or even a `Bar` -- down the road anymore).